# Symbolic predicate logic "a variable belongs to naturals but bigger than two"

Tags: logic

I have written a function and I would like to write at the end "where the variable $x$ belong to the naturals but bigger than $2$" but be translated into symbolic predicate logic. I am writing it as:
$$
(x\in\mathbb N)\wedge(x>2).
$$
I would like to ask if it correct or not.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how serious you are about "symbolic predicate logic". Probably, you're fine.

But in logic $\mathbb N$ is a semantic object (the standard model of arithmetic), you wouldn't have that in your language of first-order logic.

If your intention is to formulate the condition in a particular formal theory, like [PA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) or [ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), then it will depend on the language/resources of that theory. 
E.g. in ZF it could be written as $x\in \omega\land x>2$, $\omega$ being the finite ordinals ($\approx$natural numbers).
In PA all objects are natural numbers, so it's simply: $x>2$ ($>$ defined) or, purely $\neg x=0\land\neg x=S0\land\neg x=SS0$ (where $S$ is built-in successor function).

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is the successor function,
you could write
$\exists y \in \mathbb{N} \mid x = S(S(y))
$.